# Synonym of 'making sense' in noun form

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I would like to ask whether my application for a given position makes sense.
That is, given some circumstances, does it really make sense for me to apply for the position?

> Could you kindly please assess the *make-sense-ability* of my
>   application given the above circumstances?

More specifically, a word that would convey the fact that the application is not futile and that is has indeed a purpose (and thus makes sense) given the circumstances, would be a good fit.

I am not looking for feasibility nor viability, both of which pertain to *the state or degree of being easily or conveniently done* - not what I am asking for.

I would guess that words such as *legitimacy* or *justifiability* (if that noun exists) would come closer to what is needed.

I thought that a noun derived from the adjective *sensible* (characteristic of sth making sense) would fit, but *sensibility* is is off-track, since it pertains to emotions.

Perhaps *purposefulness*? (again, given that word exists)

Comment: You could quite reasonably ask about [*the **credibility** of your application.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+credibility+of+your+application%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Doesn't _credibility_ pertain to _the quality of being trusted and believed in_, which is not an issue here or _the quality of being convincing or believable_ - also not central to the topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it sounds like you are informing about the [***reasonability***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reasonability) of an application.

> NOUN
>   The quality or capacity of being reasonable; reasonableness.

[***reasonable***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reasonable)

> ADJECTIVE
>   1 Having sound judgement; fair and sensible.
>   1.1 Based on good sense.

References:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reasonability
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reasonable

Answer (score 2):

[Appropriate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/appropriate), as an adjective, would work well. The question would be someting like "Given my severe claustrophobia would it be *appropriate* for me to apply for the position of darkroom technician?

Answer (score 1):

**Clarity**

> Clearness or lucidity as to perception or understanding; freedom from indistinctness or ambiguity.

So you could use it in the sentence as follows:

> Could you kindly please assess the **clarity** of my application given the above circumstances?

Comment: So that would be: _Could you kindly please assess the **clearness or lucidity as to perception or understanding** of my application given the above circumstances?_ I can see some connection to my intended meaning but I am worried this might be confounded with whether my application is clear and understandable - which is not really the point.

Comment: @wit221, Erm, in what way does something "making sense" not pertain to its being clear and understandable; they're synonymous?

Comment: I was looking for a word which would convey that the application would not be futile - that there indeed was sense in submitting it given the said circumstances.

Comment: @wit211 Then your question needs re-wording; clarity definitely fits for *make-sense-ability* but less so for whether there is any point in applying. Which question are you asking?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edited the question to refocus its target.

Comment: @wit221 Your edit has not changed the misleading aspect; *make-sense-ability*.

Answer (score 1):

**Intelligibility**

> The quality or condition of being intelligible; capability of being understood.
>   ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intelligibility))

This is perhaps a word that fits exactly but sounds slightly verbose.

> Could you kindly please assess the **intelligibility** of my application given the above circumstances?

Comment: I am afraid this is similar to clarity and is most often used in the context of something being easy to understand, like someone's speech or writing, which would confuse the reader of my question. Am I wrong?

Comment: @wit221 No, quite correct, how does that not answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like a job for *applicability*. Of course, that sounds a bit weird following up application, which might make a rephrasing sensible.

> *applicability [MASS NOUN]* The quality of being relevant or appropriate.
>
> the case has raised questions about the applicability of local laws to acts committed by foreigners outside the country

Secondly I suggest *appropriateness*.

> *appropriateness [MASS NOUN]* The quality of being suitable or proper in the circumstances.
>
> some staff members question the appropriateness of this practice

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***eligibility***?

> Could you kindly assess the **eligibility** of my
>   application given the above circumstances?

M-W:

> **[eligible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eligible)**
>   *adjective*
>
> 1 a :  qualified to participate or be chosen
>
> *eligible to retire*
>
> - eligibility *noun*

ODO:

> **[eligibility](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eligibility)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> [MASS NOUN] The state of having the right to do or obtain something
>   through satisfaction of the appropriate conditions.
>
> ‘restrictions governing the eligibility of candidates’

Answer (score 1):

I believe ***admissibility*** comes close.

> Could you kindly assess the ***admissibility*** of my application
>   given the above circumstances?

M-W:

> **[admissible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/admissible)**
>   *adjective*
>
> **1** :  capable of being allowed or conceded :  permissible 
>   **2** :  capable or worthy of being admitted
>
> - **admissibility**  *noun*
>
> The judge decided that the confession was admissible in court.